# CustomUserSession Distributed Cache Issue

Tags: servicestack

I have created my own CustomUserSession which extends AuthUserSession, thus allowing me to override onAuthenticated and set a couple of extra properties.

I have registered my CustomUserSession as follows:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider(),
                                      new CredentialsAuthProvider()
                }));
```

All works great when I login to the service that makes use of my CustomUserSession, i.e. I can see that an entry is added to the distributed cache table (CacheEntry).

However, when I call a secure method on a second (micro) service that is also configured to use distributed caching, I receive a 401 HTTP status code (unauthorised).

If I make both services use AuthUserSession the distributed cache works fine and I can call secure methods on the second service having logged in on the first service.

It appears this a defect / issue in ServiceStack, i.e. distributed cache doesn't work with CustomUserSession?

Is there a known workaround or alternative way of getting distributed caching to work when implementing a CustomUserSession?

Adding more information as required, my CustomUserSession is as follows:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public bool ProfileCompleted { get; set; }

        public bool RegistrationVerified { get; set; }

        public IUserAuthManager UserAuthManager { get; set; }

        public IRegistrationManager RegistrationManager { get; set; }

        public CustomUserSession()
        {
            HostContext.Container.AutoWire(this);
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

            // Check if user profile has been completed
            ProfileCompleted = UserAuthManager.ProfileIsComplete(session);

            // Check if the user has verified their comms details
            RegistrationVerified = UserAuthManager.RegistrationIsVerified(session);
        }

        public override void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService)
        {
            base.OnRegistered(registrationService);

            var regDto = registrationService.Request.Dto as Register;

            if (regDto != null)
            {

                RegistrationManager.ProcessNewRegistration(regDto);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Registration DTO NULL Reference");
            }
        }
    }
```

My AppHost Config method for Service 1 is as follows:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider(),
                                      new CredentialsAuthProvider()
                }));

            //Register global CORS Headers
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); 

            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

            AddGlobalResponseFilter();

            SetupAutoMapper();

            container.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AppHost).Assembly);

            container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();

            var connStr = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UserAuthConnStr");
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connStr, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));

            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
            var userStore = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();       

            //Create 'CacheEntry' RDBMS table if it doesn't exist already
            container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();

            RegisterProfileComponents(container);
            RegisterExtendedRegComponents(container);

            CreateAuthTables(userStore);

            ConfigureMessageQueue(container);
        }
```

Here is my GlobalResponseFilter which is called above:

```
private void AddGlobalResponseFilter()
        {
            GlobalResponseFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
            {
                if (httpReq.OperationName == "Authenticate")
                {
                    if (!httpResp.IsClosed)
                    {
                        httpResp.AddHeader("Profile-Complete", ((CustomUserSession)httpReq.GetSession()).ProfileCompleted.ToString());

                        httpResp.AddHeader("Reg-Verified", ((CustomUserSession)httpReq.GetSession()).RegistrationVerified.ToString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

My second (micro )service config method contains the following:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {new CredentialsAuthProvider()
                }));

            //Register global CORS Headers
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); 

            container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UserAuthConnStr"), SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
            container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();
```

Note that the second service uses a standard AuthUserSession, only the first service uses the CustomUserSession.

I can see in Chrome Rest Console & Fiddler that the SessionId's are being passed correctly to the 2nd service, however I still get the 401 response.

If I change the first service to use the standard AuthUserSession, all works ok.

** Please see below for the REQUEST & RESPONSE contents for when the 401 is returned:

REQUEST:

```
GET http://localhost:8088/exercise/analytics?DateFrom=01%2F01%2F2014 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8088
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: ss-id=X83GVWXwyMHIWXEw6X1k; ss-pid=ABjuJFUqyHkMUvI7ssyv; X-UAId=10005
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.022 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
WWW-Authenticate: credentials realm="/auth/credentials"
Date: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 22:00:44 GMT

0
```

Regards
John

Comment: In addition to satisfying the rules in the banner above, please write your question so that it is readable, and not simply a wall of text.

Comment: There's not nearly enough info to be able to diagnose what's going wrong here. What does your `CustomUserSession` look like? Does it look like [the example in Session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack)? i.e. that inherits `AuthUserSession` with `[DataContract]` attributes? Otherwise can you post the full output of the `401` HTTP Request/Response. (i.e using Fiddler, WebInspector or WireShark). Does it contain ServiceStack's session cookies?

Comment: Thanks for responding mythz, I have added the extra detail as required, please see above.

Comment: @JohnC can you add `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` to your CustomerUserSession as it inherits from [AuthUserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs) which is a DataContract. You also shouldn't have any dependencies on serialized models/DTO's, just pull deps from `IServiceBase` param or `HostContext.TryResolve<T>` when you need them.

Comment: Hi @mythz, adding [DataContract] & [DataMember] to my CustomUserSession made no difference, I still got the 401 response.

Comment: Is this because I use CustomUserSession in my 1st service and AuthUserSession in my 2nd (own process) service?

Comment: @JohnC Could be, if it means you're trying to serialize in one type but deserialize it back into another.

Comment: I've tried using a CustomUserSession in both services and removing dependencies, i.e. using HostContext.TryResolve<T> where required, I still get a 401.

Comment: Given AuthUserSession works in a distributed cache configuration, it does appear this might be a ServiceStack defect?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here, but I'm using OrmLite CacheClient in a few places with multiple auth providers tested on different RDBMS backends and it's working fine. Maybe check to what you're doing different with [HttpBenchmarks Configuration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks/blob/master/src/BenchmarksAnalyzer/Global.asax.cs#L51-L71).

Comment: Thanks for your help @mythz...much appreciated.

Comment: For now I'll stick with the AuthUserSession on my services because this works great  with distributed caching (SQL SERVER backend). I'll come up with a manual workaround for what I was trying to do.